# Issue passing an object and array as a multi-cast type into a function argument for Angular 2 (Typescript Question)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My problem is very simple. I want to pass an object (of Class CircuitBreaker) into my arguments.  I want it to be reusable, however, so I would like to also use `|` to pass an array of this same Class as well.

This creates syntax errors where the compiler is confused on accepting array functions (such as .some)

> Property 'some' does not exist on type 'CircuitBreakerThresholdBreakdown | CircuitBreakerThresholdBreakdown[]

and/or a property of a potential object:

> Property 'threshold' does not exist on type 'CircuitBreakerThresholdBreakdown | CircuitBreakerThresholdBreakdown[]

What am I missing here?

```
public thresholdFunction(cBreakdowns: CircuitBreaker | CircuitBreaker[]): boolean {
    if (cBreakdowns.length > 1) {
        return cBreakdowns.some(singleBreakdown => {
            return singleBreakdown.breakdown.count > singleBreakdown.threshold.maximum ||
            singleBreakdown.breakdown.count < singleBreakdown.threshold.minimum;
        });
    } else {
        return cBreakdowns.breakdown.count < cBreakdowns.threshold.minimum;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your `if` statement this way:

```
if (cBreakdowns instanceof Array) {
 // ...
} else {
 // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use spread operator in paramter `(...)`.

- When calling the function if you want to pass `object` then use `thresholdFunction(obj);`.
- If you want to pass `array` use `thresholdFunction(...array);`. And update your code like below.
- You can also pass multiple `objects` with `thresholdFunction(obj1, obj2, obj3);`

---

```
public thresholdFunction(...cBreakdowns: CircuitBreaker[]): boolean {
    return cBreakdowns.some(singleBreakdown => {
        return singleBreakdown.breakdown.count > singleBreakdown.threshold.maximum ||
            singleBreakdown.breakdown.count < singleBreakdown.threshold.minimum;
    });
}
```